# Declare String then open string from Path with Cocoa

Tags: cocoa

I've Declared a string Like so

NSString* fileName = [files objectAtIndex:i];
            NSLog(fileName);

NSImage* imageFromBundle = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName];

and want to use that filename to open a file in a different directory.
I came up with this

NSImage* imageFromBundle2; 
imageFromBundle2 = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/rhaynes/Documents/works4/" filename ];

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that your fileName string is actually a file name, like "myImage.png". A lot of the Objective-C docs refer to a file name when they really mean file path - so sometimes it's confusing.

What you want to do is create an NSString that represents the complete path to the file you want to load. For instance, you could say:

```
NSString * path = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"/Users/rhaynes/Documents/works4/%@", fileName];
```

That line creates a new NSString using the format string and parameters provided (the %@ in the format string indicates that the string value of fileName should be inserted there.) StringWithFormat is a really powerful function, so you should definitely check it out in the docs.

Then you could call initWithContentsOfFile:path, and it should give you the image you want.

Comment: WoW U are the MAN. Thanks for the Quick Reply, You have gotten me closer to my answer, however my log file shows the complete path to my file instead of just the fiename

2009-06-06 23:22:40.188 appagain2[26864] Users/rhaynes/Documents/works4//Users/rhaynes/Documents/works3/work1.jpg

Do you know of a way to get the filename only like
Users/rhaynes/Documents/works4/work1.jpg

Comment: Ok. So that means that your fileName variable is actually a full path. What you really want is just the last part: "work1.jpg". Then you can append that to the "right" path. The Objective-C string class provides a neat function called lastPathComponent that will return just that part.

So in the stringWithFormat: line I put in my answer, just replace fileName with [fileName lastPathComponent]. That should do it!

Answer (score 0):

> NSString* fileName = [files objectAtIndex:i]; NSLog(fileName);

Don't pass non-hard-coded strings as format-string arguments. If they contain format specifiers, you'll get garbage or a crash. (Try this with `fileName = @"foo%sbar"`, for example. Then try it with `fileName = @"foo%fbar"` for even more fun.)

Your NSLog statement should be:

```
NSLog(@"%@", fileName);
```

> [I] want to use that filename to open a file in a different directory. I came up with this
>
> ```
> NSImage* imageFromBundle2; imageFromBundle2 = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/rhaynes/Documents/works4/" filename ];
> ```

You can only concatenate string literals this way; as you've no doubt seen for yourself, this is a syntax error when one of the strings isn't a literal.

First off, if `fileName` *is* actually a pathname, you'll need to use `lastPathComponent` to get the actual filename. So:

```
NSString *path = [files objectAtIndex:i];
NSString *filename = [path lastPathComponent];
```

Then, use `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` to tack this onto the new superpath.

```
NSString *desiredFilenamePath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
```

Now you have the pathname you wanted to pass to NSImage's initializer.